# How to suppress Composer script echoing command executed?

Tags: php, composer-php

If I specify a script in my `composer.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "@php phpunit -c phpunit.xml"
}
```

Composer will echo the command when it is executed:

```
$user> composer test
> @php @php phpunit -c phpunit.xml
PHPUnit 8.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
...
```

Is there anyway to suppress the echo'd command in Composer's output?

**EDIT:**

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
$user> composer test
PHPUnit 8.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
...
```

Comment: do you mean to supress '$user> composer test' part?

Comment: @matiit no, that's the command issued to execute the Composer script. I'd like to suppress the "@php phpunit [...]" part, which Composer echoes to `STDOUT` when you issue a command.

Comment: Does > /dev/null work? Like: "test": "@php phpunit -c phpunit.xml > /dev/null"

Comment: Oh, I just seen your edit, ignore my previous comment.

Comment: My command have grep in it, and composer behavior breaks it. My grep is feed composer command as string. :(

Answer (score 3):

You could selectively erase the output of the composer command directly:

```
composer test 2>&1 | grep -v '^> @php'
```

This will redirect the stderr in stdout and then remove all lines that starts with `> @php` (the `> @php phpunit -c phpunit.xml` line is outputted in stderr)

The final output should be:

```
$user> composer test 2>&1 | grep -v '^> @php'
PHPUnit 8.0.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
...
```

Then you could put the command in a sh script to avoid typing it every time

```
#!/bin/sh
composer test 2>&1 | grep -v '^> @php'
```

Answer (score 2):

On command line it shouldn't be possible.
You can instead save the output into a file:

```
    "tests": [
        "@php phpunit -c phpunit.xml 2>&1 | tee COMPOSER-LOG",
        "@php -v 2>&1 | tee COMPOSER-LOG"
    ]
```

Comment: Maybe piping to `/dev/null` instead of a file?

Comment: I guess it will hide the whole content and not only the command. Composer print the command to be executed. Have you tried to run the bash with shell_exec() and work with the response?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to suppress the echo'd command in Composer's output?

It doesn't actually echo the command to STDOUT; it echos it to STDERR.

So

```
composer test 2> /dev/null
```

should give you clean output - see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

also, if you're parsing composers output using software (like php `exec`) they are often only reading STDOUT, and not receive exactly what you see on the command line.